# How to change the filename when you add file into tar file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, tar

I'm creating tar file by running the script. Script is in folder A. I want to append the file into tar. The input file and tar file both are in folder B. When I am appending file to existing tar I have give absolute file path as it is in another folder and when its going to append into tar it should get renamed to the name I want.

Example:

- Script location: `/root/test/A`
- File location I want to add in tar: `/root/myFolder/B/foo`
- Tar file location: `/root/myFolder/B/archive.tar`

While appending `/root/myFolder/B/foo` to `archive.tar` it should get renamed to `bar`.

I'm trying this command but no success:

```
tar --transform='flags=r;s|/root/myFolder/B/foo|bar|' -cf archive.tar /root/myFolder/B/foo
```

It's adding file as it is with same name `/root/myFolder/B/foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause is `tar` automatically removing leading `/`:

> tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

It seems it gets removed before the regex execution. So you need to remove the leading `/` in the pattern too:

```
tar --transform='flags=r;s|root/myFolder/B/foo|bar|' -cf archive.tar /root/myFolder/B/foo
```

or use `-P` switch

```
 -P, --absolute-names
       don't strip leading '/'s from file names
```

As an alternative you could switch to the files folder with `-C`, then you don't need to replace the path:

```
tar --transform='flags=r;s|foo|bar|' -cf archive.tar -C /root/myFolder/B/ foo
```

Comment: @nilesh_101 if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it